# Responsive design issue - with modal popup

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, adaptive-design

I have developed a custom modal popup, which is used as a generic component in my project. Different content/html is passed inside of the modal as to from where it is opened.

Plunk - http://plnkr.co/edit/aApQZhgMZJkMAjLtjF5P?p=preview

HTML:

```
  <body>
    <div>
      <button class="one">One</button>
      <button class="two">Two</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
      <div>Content specific to button here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="backdrop"></div>
  </body>
```

CSS

```
button{width:50px; height:20px; margin-right:10px;}
.modal{position:absolute; top:50px; left:50px; height:100px;background:#ededed; display:none;z-index:10;    }
.backdrop{position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;background: #000; opacity: .5;
  display:none; z-index:9;}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".one").on("click",function(){
    $(".modal, .backdrop").show();
    $(".modal div").width(50).html("Content 1 here")
  })

  $(".two").on("click",function(){
    $(".modal, .backdrop").show();
    $(".modal div").width(300).html("Content 2 here")
  })

  $(".backdrop").on("click",function(){
    $(".modal, .backdrop").hide();
  })
}
```

)

As shown in plunk above, when button one is clicked the content inside the popup is less, hence the size of popup is very small. But when the popup is called from another button, there is a lot of content in there. 
Now, I have to make this work on majorly all platforms - mobile (iphone/nexus), tablet (nexus/ipad/ipadmini) and desktop browsers.

Problem I am facing:

1) When modal is opened from button One, the width of modal would be very low as there is not much content, just a small list with few lines of text.

2) The modal from 2nd button occupies whole screen on the mobile phones, hence I wanted to keep the width of modal as 100%. But if I do that, it occupies the full screen on tablets and desktop as well, which is not needed, it should only take 50% on tab and desktop. And I also need to make sure the modal remains as small as it was in point 1 or when opened from button one.

3) The modal is directly appended to body tag

4) Since modal is generic component, I just want to keep its styling same irrespective of from where it is called. And to take care of different instances, the div inside modal can be used for varying widths.

So, considering all 4 points, I am not able to make it work across all platforms, I was able to get it done for desktop/tablets ,but not for phone, since it needs 100% screen there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into media queries in the CSS...

Something like:

```
.modal { width:50%; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { .modal { width:100%; }}
```

This will make the `.modal` class 50% on all devices, but 100% on mobiles.

Comment: Hey, I kind of realised that for my requirements, I had to use js, to determine the browser viewport and then do things accordingly. Media queries alone coudlnt help, but anyway, thanks for the inputs.